# modelling interaction terms in random effects and coding of daytime in growth models lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, multilevel-analysis

I have a question regarding model setup in R and after a long and thorough search I did not find a thread answering either of my two questions:

Im gonna describe the setup first:

Its a repeated measures dataset with two different interventions (food and training), each of them have two levels. All participants underwent each combination of conditions.
Hormone samples were collected over the course of the day.
Age and BMI are included as covariates.

A reproducible data set is this one:

```
ID <- rep(rep(c("A","B","C"),each=5),4)
TIME <- rep(paste(sprintf("%02i",9:13),"00",sep=":"),12)
training <- rep(rep(rep(c("T1","T2"),each=5),each=3),2)
food <- c(rep(rep(c("F1","F2"),each=5),each=3),rep(rep(c("F2","F1"),each=5),each=3))
hormone <- rnorm(n = 60,mean=5,sd=2)
BMI <- as.numeric(rep(rep(c(22,27,25),each=5),4))
age <- as.numeric(rep(rep(c(26,27,23),each=5),4))
DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID,TIME,training,food,hormone,BMI,age))


DF$BMI <- scale(as.numeric(DF$BMI))
DF$age <- scale(as.numeric(DF$age))
DF$hormone <- as.numeric(as.character(DF$hormone))
```

Now I have 2 main issues:

1) At first I would like to assess the interaction effect of both interventions on baseline hormone levels.
For that, I setup the following model:

```
model.df <- DF[DF$TIME=="09:00",]

m1 <- lmer(hormone~training*food+age+BMI+(1+training*food|ID),model.df)
```

However, this model cannot be setup, because

```
Error: number of observations (=16) <= number of random effects (=16) for           term (1 + training * food | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

It does work, when I exclude the interaction term from the random effect:

m1 <- lmer(hormone~training*food+age+BMI+(1+training+food|ID),model.df)

I am now wondering whether this is still a valid model to test for the interaction?
My Null-Model would accordingly be:

```
m0 <- lmer(hormone~training+food+age+BMI+(1+training+food|ID),model.df)
```

Now to the second point:

2)

We also want to monitor the hormonal changes over the time course.

However, I am not sure how to include the time of day in the model.

As pointed out in this thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245866/is-hour-of-day-a-categorical-variable

it can be included as a circular variable, however, since my sampling does not cover the entire day I am not sure how to implement this in my case.
Can anyone help?

In addition, I am not sure how to setup the model including the time-variable.

We are still interested in the interaction of both interventions, so I would setup something like the following model. (this now assumes time as numeric)

```
model.df <- DF
model.df$TIME <- as.numeric(model.df$TIME)

m2 <- lmer(hormone~training*food*TIME+age+BMI+(1+training*food*TIME||ID),model.df)
```

However: 1) This model does not converge

```
Warning messages:
1: In commonArgs(par, fn, control, environment()) :
  maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended.
2: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),:
  convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function   evaluations exceeded
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,      :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0035331 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

and 2)
Would you think this is an appropriate model to thest for the interaction effect over time?

It would then be tested against the following null-model:

```
m02 <- lmer(hormone~training*TIME+food*TIME+age+BMI+(1+training*TIME+food*TIME||ID),model.df)
```

I hope these arent too many questions for one thread and I would be super-happy about any pointers.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: StackOverflow posts are indeed supposed to contain a *single* question. There are at least four questions here. Can you please split them up? Also, some/most of them ("is this an appropriate model") belong on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), rather than here. (Questions about programming belong here; questions about interpretation and modeling belong there.)

Comment: PS: use `data.frame(...)` rather than `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` to avoid turning all of your numeric values into factors. Out of curiosity, can I ask where you learned that particular syntax? (We've been seeing a lot of similar examples on StackOverflow lately ...)

Comment: ok yeah i see that point. sorry ill split/migrate the question. I dont know where I picked up that syntax ;) thx for the suggestion-

Comment: I migrated this question to <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326035/including-interaction-of-conditions-in-fixed-and-random-effects-with-limited-no?noredirect=1#comment618039_326035> and <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326042/investigating-the-interaction-effect-of-two-conditions-over-time-questions-reg?noredirect=1#comment618017_326042>